# How to use selenium/standalone-chrome when deployed to different machines?

Tags: java, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver

How to use selenium/standalone-chrome when deployed to different machines?

1. I have installed docker on a remote ubuntu machine and also my local machine which is a Macbook pro.
2. I would then run the following docker image to create the needed container:
   selenium/node-chrome
3. How would I then get my automation (Java + Selenium) tests to point to the container if I cant access the hub url via local host?
4. Example url and code:

Java Code:

```
private static Driver initialiseWebTesting(boolean grid, String browser, String os) {
   if (grid) {
       try {
           driver = new WebDriverWrapper(new URL("http://1xx.1xx.xx.100:4444/wd/hub");,
                   WebInitialiser.getDesiredCapabilities(browser));
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           fail();
       }
```

Hub Url:

```
http://1xx.1xx.xx.100:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html
```

Im having problems pointing to the hub url because my automation framework is being executed from different machines therefore the ip address can always change, any ideas of how I can get round this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to hard code the URL.  Why not pass in as a command line argument to the process running your tests, or extract from an environment variable?

Presumably you know the IP address when you begin test execution?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Robbie, do you know how I can find the ip address of the running container and pass that ip address within the java program?

Comment: To do it programatically, you need access to the Docker process (via HTTP).  WIll that IP address change?

Another idea could be to run everything in docker (including the tests), then use Docker Compose to orchestrate the execution.  This provides very nice networking which allows you to use the container's name (provided by you, and therefore potential to be constant) and internal port.  This can also support multiple executions if the `project-name` is set when executing Docker Compose, as it acts as kind of namespace.

Comment: Thanks again, I dont think the ip address will change from what I can see that docker adds more 00 to the end of the inet address, so i guess it may be a case of adding more 00 to the end of the ip address which is used by the Jenkins slave agent.